# C# I/O vs C I/O

Tags: c#, c++, c, io

I have a C# program that needs to read tens to hundreds of millions of records from a flat text file. Is there is a significant performance gain from using a p/invoke call to an unmanaged C/C++ dll that handles all of the file input on a separate thread, or is it an insignificant gain in performance, such that it would be better to just handle my file IO in C#?

Comment: "[If you have two horses and you want to know which of the two is the faster then race your horses.](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)"

Comment: @Filburt if you have two horses both are very slow, then it is not important who is the jockey

Comment: @EZI Eric Lippert has a few things to say about premature optimization as well.

Comment: Unless you're willing to put some work into it, the C++ version may easily be slower--C# has some pretty darned good I/O. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ricom/archive/2005/05/10/416151.aspx

Comment: @Filburt I wish I could understand what you mean (read my comment as *"IO is slow, it is not important which language you use"*)

Comment: @EZI I was just referring to the article which basically confirms your point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably not a significant performance gain in using a C/C++ dll. The C# runs in an environment with a quite efficient JIT compiler, so my guess is that the code performance is limited by a hard disk read speed of approximately 100 MB/s. Of course, if you have an SSD, your mileage may vary.

Do note that if one record is e.g. 1000 bytes and you are reading 100 million records, that means 100 gigabytes. Reading it takes 1000 seconds, i.e. more than 15 minutes, just due to the slow speed of the hard disk drive.

Answer (score 1):

Because magnitude of difference between CPU bound code and IO bound requests you the amount of time you save by writing the code in native C will be fractions of a percent of benefit.

The only time you will see benefits of having separate native functions is when the actual instructions being executed is the bottleneck. For example crunching larges amount of numbers in RAM or calculating pixels for 3D graphics.

It is unlikely worth your time to attempt it while working with IO.